# 'Irrealistic' or 'unrealistic'?

Tags: negation, prefixes, irregular

I basically learnt that words that start with a 'm' or 'p' get 'im' as a negative prefix, whilst words starting with 'r' get 'ir' in such a case (irreverent, irrelevant).

However, I stumbled upon 'realistic'. I'm almost sure it is 'unrealistic'. A quick search on Google revealed 13 million hits for 'unrealistic'; 'irrealistic' on the contrary only results in 14.000 hits.

Therefore, is 'unrealistic' an exception to this rule?

Comment: The rule is bogus. You have to take the etymology into account. You would never say *irready* or *irruly*, either.

Comment: Do you say "unready"?  New one to me... ;-)

Comment: Ever hear of King Æthelred (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86thelred_the_Unready)?

Comment: @jae: you miss the point. As does Kelly, actually, as Æthelred's name has nothing to do with not being ready, and everything with being ill-advised (cf. German *Rat*, "counsel"). My point was that whether or not *unready*, *unround*, *unright*, and *unrude* exist, you would prefer them over *irready*, *irround*, *irright*, and *irrude* any time.

Comment: Oh, *him*.  Yeah, heard of him, just didn't recall (and of course, this singular use doesn't make "unready" a (proper) word.  Especially since it seems to be a mistranslation (according to the linked WP-article))

Comment: @jae: true, one singular and possibly erroneous usage doesn’t show that “unready” is a proper word — but a cursory look into any dictionary shows that it is one.  Admittedly, it seems to have fallen out of use somewhat in the 20th century; but it was a well-used word for quite a few centuries.

Comment: jae: *Unready* is actually a proper word. @PLL: True, one meaning of the word is now archaic. However, the meaning, *unprepared*, is still quite current.

Comment: "She was young and unready for motherhood."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The word *realistic* is negated with the prefix *un-*, which is not the same as *in-/im-/ir-*, and is not subject to the rule regarding *in-/im-/ir-*. The rule that you cited is correct, but **only for words that take the negative prefix in-/im-/ir-** (e.g. *intractable, impossible, irresponsible*). Words that are negated with *un-* always use *un-* (e.g. *untreatable, unbearable, unready*), and never vary the second letter of the prefix.

There is no general rule that will allow you to know which words take the negative prefix *un-* and which take the negative prefix *in-*.

The forms that you find on the net with the word *irrealistic* are either mistakes by non-native speakers, people being clever with word-play, or possibly people creating derivations off of the specialized linguistic term *irrealis*.

Comment: So, basically, "Theorem: A holds whenever A holds."?

Comment: @jae, kind of. If you know that the word is negated with one of *in-/im-/ir-*, then you can use the OP's rule to predict which version of the prefix to use. But if you don't know whether to negate with *un-* or *in-*, then you're pretty much hosed.

Comment: +1 — excellent answer! More examples of *un* + *r*: *unreasonable*, *unreadable*, *unrelated*, *unrated*, *unrhymed* …

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Never heard of such a rule.  Or I may have forgotten about it.  Never been a fan of rules about language anyway: you learn the rule and the myriad of exceptions (depending on rule and language in question)-  Why not just learn the words, and be done with it?

Comment: When rules often apply, it is a good idea in my opinion to learn those instead of each single word. Of course there are exceptions, but it's useful to fall back on.

Comment: Yes, and why not just learn all the sentences, instead of bothering with grammar? Patterns are for the birds.

Comment: They think differently about that at my school :o)

Comment: I didn't learned rules (or grammer, which is rules), I just learnt the language.  Just like I learn not German, I just learndit.   Seriously (no, seriously seriously), I never bothered much with grammar in school (and my grades were as one would expect ;-)).  We had a German-teacher who was all about comma rules; she had a catalog of rules for where to put commas, and most of the class learned those rules slavishly --  I didn't bother.  I learn by... osmosis, if you will.

Comment: To put it in context: I know it's "unruly", and "not ready" and "irrelevant"... but I don't see, nor do I need, any rules behind that.  So, I don't bother with them anymore.  Not for the actual activity of speaking/writing.  As an academic/intellectual exercise, grammar (and "rules") can be fun... but mostly by amusing oneself with the exceptions.  But that's MVPO (my very personal opinion).

Comment: People are *much* better at learning the rules of grammar, punctuation, and spelling "by osmosis" than at learning them consciously. A 3-year-old knows enough about the grammar, vocabulary, and diction of his or her native language to fill books and books. But that doesn't mean the 3-year-old hasn't learned the rules. You can tell by the mistakes kids make that they know the rules (subconsciously). Mainly they don't know all the exceptions yet.